# Where is my credentials / password stored when I try to push to a repository in GitHub using HTTPS?

Tags: git, github

So I cloned a repository down from GitHub using the HTTPS address.

I can push commits to it without entering a password or any credentials.

I know with SSH, my SSH private key is stored in the ~/.ssh folder. With HTTPS, how am I able to push to GitHub without needing to set a password. Where is my password / credential set?

And can I clear this? Is there a way to make it so I need to enter the login and password each time using HTTPS?

Comment: minus vote because???

Comment: You might have cloned the repository using `git clone https://username:password@github.com/blah/blahblah.git`. That's i why it's not asking for password.

Answer (score 0):

You may have cached your credentials locally. If you're using OS X, you might try this:

https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/